# How to change theme in app settings

Tags: java, android, settings, oncreate, onpause

I am working on an app in which I would like the user to be able to pick from a list of color options in the settings (all code shown below). However when they do it does not change after you settings activity. It changes when you leave the activity(say home) and come back. I believe this is because `onCreate()` is not being called, The problem is that if I do `setContentView`() again the whole app is unresponsive. And if I do `recreate()` It crashes because of the music player (again code below). Please do leave an answer even if you just think it will work. Thanks in advance.

Code:
SettingsActivity.java (also cant get the bar to change on this one)

```
    public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String themeName = settings.getString("theme", "DarkBlue");
        int theme = MyThemer.getThemeid(themeName);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20){
            int themeDark = MyThemer.getColorPrimaryDark(themeName);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(themeDark));
        }
        setTheme(theme);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.settings_activity);

        String themName = settings.getString("theme", "DarkBlue");
        int barColor = MyThemer.getColorPrimary(themName);

        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
        Toolbar bar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.settings_toolbar, root, false);
        bar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(barColor));
        root.addView(bar, 0); // insert at top
        bar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Code:
MainActivity.java

onCreate()

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    mySetTheme();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);
```

setTheme()

```
private void mySetTheme(){
    themeName = settings.getString("theme", "DarkBlue");
    int theme = MyThemer.getThemeid(themeName);
    setTheme(theme);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20){
        int themeDark = MyThemer.getColorPrimaryDark(themeName);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(themeDark));
    }
}
```

onResume()

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    playMusic = settings.getBoolean("playMusic", true);
    if(playMusic){
        backgroundMusicPlayer = new BackgroundMusicPlayer();
        backgroundMusicPlayer.execute(getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

onPause()

```
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(playMusic){
        backgroundMusicPlayer.cancelMusic();
        backgroundMusicPlayer.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

backgroundMusicPlayer.java

```
public class BackgroundMusicPlayer extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void>{

    MediaPlayer player;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Context... params) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(params[0], R.raw.background);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.setVolume(50,50);
        player.start();
        return null;
    }

    public void cancelMusic(){
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        player.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had to replace `finish();` with

```
Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(home);
```

Thank you so much for reading my question.